# Issue while adding toolchain in IBM Bluemix Dedicated

Tags: ibm-cloud, toolchain

I am using IBM Bluemix Dedicated. I want to edit code and found the **Add toolchain** option, but when I click it, it opens a new pop-up with the following error:

`404: resource not found`

Note that I was to share the code repository with another developer.

Answer (score 2):

ADD TOOLCHAIN is a function offered by Bluemix DevOps Services to associate your application with a continuous delivery toolchain. 
Now, this button shouldn't have been surfaced yet, as DevOps Services are still being configured in this environment.

Sorry for the inconvenience (just avoid pressing this button for now). 
We'll resolve this shortly.

Comment: do we have an idea when this wil be available? Also everytime I open an application I have a confusing popup saying `Create Toolchain` and the current date ...